# Problems with the keyboarddddddd

Tags: power, keyboard

I have recently gotten my raspberry pi and I have plugged in my wireless keyboard but am having difficulties typing. Just trying to log in, I get piiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii when I just type pi. So I read about this and it said it was because keyboard is taking too much power so I purchased a usb hub with a external power source but I still have the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix it? is there some option that I have to enable to stop this? 
Also if it helps somehow I use the **microsoft wireless 800 desktop keyboard**

Comment: Which hub are you using? I am assuming you are plugging the keyboard dongle into the hub. What else do you have plugged into the Pi's USB ports?

Comment: I bought a staples USB hub with a external power source(so it has a seperate power source) and I plugged that into the raspberry pi and then I plugged in the receiver for tehe wireless keyboard into the hub, I also tried using a wifi reciever in the hub but I tried with it plugged and not and it still has this problem

Comment: Is the keyboard on this list of known working keyboards http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Keyboards? How are you poewering the Pi? Have you run through the Power and Keyboard checks on the troubleshooting page http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting?

Comment: D: it's in the problems keyboard! I wonder what sticky keys means?

Comment: Sticky keys are what you are describing the key acts like it is held down continually.

Comment: Oh so this means thats theres no solution.... thanks (Oh why did I buy the microsoft keyboard, I knew that staples sale was too good to true....)

Comment: I would not rule out a solution, especially before troubleshooting any potential power issues. But as your keyboard is not listed on the known working list you may need to get a new keyboard.

Comment: My solutionw as getting a usb hib with a seperate power source but that didnt work, I guess i'll just use my older keyboard thats not wireless, thansk again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With both your keyboard AND wifi dongle functioning improperly, I can come to only three conclusions:

1. The set you got your Pi in (which, if you're from the UK, is from Maplin I presume) is defective with your keyboard and wifi dongle broken already.
2. The USB hub that came with it is broken and will not work properly.
3. Your Pi's USB ports are damaged in some way.

Comment: only the wfii keybaord doesnt work so i switched to my older dell keyboard and that works now but its not wireless.... and my wifi dongle was working before i tested it on my ubuntu computer so i think ubuntu did something to it but i was looking for someway to reformat it to wrok for the raspberry pi and ithinknthat the usb ports work since i and non wireless keyboard works perfectly and so does my usb so the ports arent broken....